# Block within block in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am trying to get some variable from Pillar and passing a variable as name of key to get from Pillar but something seems to be missing. I tried a few combinations but none seem to work.

In first line - I am getting key - house_name and then in second line I want to dynamically get the appropriate value for that key from Pillar. Part of key is static (homes:list) and part dynamic (house_name)

```
{% for house_name in event_data.house_list|list %}
{% set home_def = salt['pillar.get']('homes:list:{{ house_name }}') %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

When I hardcode the house_name in second line - things work fine - which means something in rendering of the key with namespace is wrong. A few combinations which I tried but don't work of second line:

```
{% set home_def = salt['pillar.get']('homes:list:'{{ house_name }}) %}
{% set home_def = salt['pillar.get']("homes:list:{{ house_name }}") %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need use `{{}}` brackets in `set` statement

```
{% for house_name in event_data.house_list|list %}
{% set home_def = salt['pillar.get']('homes:list:{}'.format(house_name)) %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks a ton. I realise that I am missing some basic syntax documentation - any pointers?

Comment: In Jinja2 the double curly braces are used as a print statement. If you access variables inside tags don’t put the braces around them. See `variables` section in documentation: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#variables

Comment: how would it work if there are two dynamic values something like homes:list:{}:{} where the two parentheses is where I need to put my two variables

Comment: 'homes:list:{}:{}'.format(var1, var2). You can read more about `format` in python documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: thanks a ton, that link is super helpful. Looks like time to wear some Python hats :)